# Flutter build method keeps rebuilding a referenced method that's in another file

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Apologies if I am articulating it poorly but I have a main file called

> Homescreen.dart

Two other files called

> category_builder.dart

and

> post_builder.dart
> respectively.

In my homescreen file I have a scaffold being returned that has an app bar and a body. Now in the body I have a listview builder that builds my home screen with categories on the top and posts below it.

For ref heres my home screen code:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('createdDate', descending: true)
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SizedBox(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: const [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.newspaper_outlined,
                                color: active,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Boards',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: highlights,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 95,
                          child: const BuildCat(),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  //index -= 1;
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: PostBuilder(
                        postCallack: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.white,
            ));
          }
        },
      ),
```

Now every time I scroll down at the bottom of the list, and when I scroll back up the category list is rebuild and reloaded, which is something I'm trying to avoid. I did try different thinks such as storing it in a variable and initializing it in initstate, initializing the Firestore query in the state of the stateful widget. But noting worked. Any help will be much apprectiated.

Also heres whats in Category file:

```
class BuildCat extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildCat({super.key});

  @override
  State<BuildCat> createState() => _BuildCatState();
}

class _BuildCatState extends State<BuildCat> {
  List? catDataList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    catdata();
  }

  Future<void> catdata() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('boards')
        .doc('Boards')
        .get()
        .then((value) => catDataList = value.data()!['BoardsList']);
    setState(() {
      catDataList;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.separated(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (catDataList == null) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
              );
            }

            return BuildCard(
                catDataList![index]['id'], catDataList![index]['img']);
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const SizedBox(width: 10);
          },
          itemCount: catDataList == null ? 0 : catDataList!.length),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid rebuilding the `FutureBuilder`'s state each time, you should not re-create the connection to Firestore every time the widget gets recreated. Instead initialize the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('createdDate', descending: true).get()` in the state of a stateful widget, and use it from there each time. If you've already tried that, edit your question to show that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try that, but unfortunately it didn't work. I think what's happening is that when there is a stateful widget in another file, and when you reference that into the main file it becomes a child. So some how the main screen is telling the child widget to rebuil, possibly to see if there was a change in the state. Hence the entire file with child widget reloads. Although if I make it a stateless widget, it works but now I cant initialize or setState of future builders get() data.